# is it possible to access and change filters on a power bi report from an embeded power app?

Tags: powerbi, powerapps

I have an embedded power app set up within a power bi report and I want to be able to read the filters that are imposed on the power apps data.

the goal is to be able to capture the filters so that I can use them again at a later date. To paint a clearer picture, I want [these data filter values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynuOC.png) in a power apps variable.

it this something that is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the [filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/control-report-filters) using [getFilters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/control-report-filters#get-filters) method of a report, page or visual. But probably what you are looking for is [bookmarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/report-bookmarks). If you [capture current state as a bookmark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/report-bookmarks#capture-and-get-a-current-view-as-a-bookmark-object):

```
let capturedBookmark = await report.bookmarksManager.capture();
```

You can [apply it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/report-bookmarks#apply-a-captured-bookmark-state-on-report-load-or-during-a-session) later to restore this state:

```
await report.bookmarksManager.applyState(capturedBookmark.state);
```

Comment: Hello, i did a bit of research with this and it looks to me like this is only available when embedding a power bi report into a web page, if i did use embedded power bi would there be a way for my js code to talk to my power app which is embedded inside of the report? or am i going about this wrong?